# Read the file and assign values to another file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I want to read the file and assign the values to variables whic is in another file using shell script.

For example I have file as **myconf**

```
cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh" 

user="rhqadmin" 

passwd="janre" 

file1="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid.js"  
file2="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid" 
file3="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid.js"   
file4="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid" 
file5="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertid"
```

and my script in another file as **testconf**

`$cli -u $user -p $passwd -s $host -f $file3 > $file4`

I want to get the values for the variables(`cli`,`user` etc) from **myconf** file. Used while loop to read the values it has been assigning the entire line `cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh"` to `$cli`. Need to assign only the values after the field separator `=` to my variable

*Example:*

> echo $cli 
>     should print /opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh
>     not as cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh"

I cant change **myconf** file it is predefined one. Please help on this

Answer (score 2):

> You have to use [source](http://ss64.com/bash/source.html) command, which  Read and execute commands
>   from the filename argument in the current shell context.

```
$cat test.sh
cli="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh" user="rhqadmin" passwd="janre"
file1="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid.js"
file2="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/agentresourceid"
file3="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid.js"
file4="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertresourceid"
file5="/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/samples/alertid"

$cat test2.sh
source test.sh
echo $cli

$./test2.sh
/opt/Solartis_Monitoring/JON_CLI/bin/rhq-cli.sh
```

> How to do it(read only variables) with loop , I would not recommend to use this method. And I will never use it by myself. So I am adding this answer only for showing some techniques.
>   Bash operates with [`IFS`(internal field separator)](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) variable, and we can change it to `=` - it will help us to split variable from data in config file.

```
IFS=" ="

while read -r name data ruser data1 pwd data2; do
  declare $name=$data
 if [[  $ruser != "" ]]; then
    declare $ruser=$data1
    declare $pwd=$data2
 fi
done < test.sh

echo $file1
echo $cli
echo $file5
echo $passwd
echo $user
```

Here you can find more about [declare](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/declareref.html)

Comment: Thanks Arseniy.It worked .. just want to confirm that so it will invoke all the commands, variables from file to the shell where  i am executing the script rit??
Is any other option to do this like using while loop??

Comment: Arseniy, but it will not assign the values to variable rit.
For example if i give  if i want to assign passwd="janre"  from conf file to the script which uses the variable passwd